# Push some ObservableCollection items in a GridControl into another ObservableCollection XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress, multi-select

I'd like to bind an ObservableCollection to a DevExpress GridControl but it's not working...

My XAML code:

```
     <dxg:GridColumn Header="Categorie" FieldName="SelectetProgrammCategorieIds">
                    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings ItemsSource="{Binding AlleCategorien, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" ValueMember="ID" DisplayMember="Name">
                            <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings.StyleSettings>
                                <dxe:CheckedComboBoxStyleSettings/>
                            </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings.StyleSettings>
                        </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings>
                    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                </dxg:GridColumn>
```

SelectetProgrammCategorieIds is an OBC and AlleCategorien is my list with All Categories. I want do separate and load some marked items from AlleCategorien into SelectetProgrammCategorieIds

greetings Venson

Comment: Would you share the full grid Xaml and the version of the DevExpress controls you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course im using it on two different positions here is the smallest:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Unattended_Tool.View.UserControls.Admin.UserControls.Detail"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 

         xmlns:dxc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"   
         xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid" 
         xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors" 
         xmlns:dxlc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/layoutcontrol" 

         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<dxlc:GroupBox MinimizeElementVisibility="Visible" IsManipulationEnabled="True" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <dxg:GridControl Name="GridControlUser" ItemsSource="{Binding AlleICTSUser, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoExpandAllGroups="True" ShowBorder="True" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:TableView Name="tableViewGrid" FocusedRow="{Binding SelecetetUser, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                    <dxg:TableView.InputBindings>
                        <KeyBinding Key="Del" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding RemoveICTSUserCommand}"/>
                        <KeyBinding Key="N" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding AddICTSUserCommand}"/>
                    </dxg:TableView.InputBindings>
                </dxg:TableView>
            </dxg:GridControl.View>

            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Name" Header="Name"/>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Password" Header="Password" AllowEditing="{Binding SelecetetUser.CanEditPassword, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                        <dxe:PasswordBoxEditSettings IsEnabled="{Binding CanEditPassword}" />
                    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                </dxg:GridColumn>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="CanEditPassword" Header="CanEdit">
                    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                        <dxe:CheckEditSettings />
                    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                </dxg:GridColumn>

                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Categorie" FieldName="SelectetProgrammCategorieIds">
                    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings ItemsSource="{Binding AlleCategorien, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" ValueMember="ID" DisplayMember="Name">
                            <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings.StyleSettings>
                                <dxe:CheckedComboBoxStyleSettings/>
                            </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings.StyleSettings>
                        </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings>
                    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                </dxg:GridColumn>

            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        </dxg:GridControl>

    </Grid>
</dxlc:GroupBox>
```

Ok i Found a way but it isent the True thing it is a "littlebit" dirty i hope there is an other way. My target class must looks like this:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using Unattended_Tool.View.DataStore;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    namespace Unattended_Tool
    {
public class ICTSPrinter : IDataErrorInfo
{
    string _name;
    string _versionsname;
    string _location;
    ObservableCollection<int> _categorie;

    public ObservableCollection<int> Categorie
    {
        get { return _categorie; }
        set { _categorie = value; }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public object SelectetProgrammCategorieIds
    {
        get { return (Object)Categorie; }
        set {                 Categories = new ObservableCollection<int>((value as IEnumerable<Object>).ToObservableCollection<int>()) { };
    }

    public string Location
    {
        get { return _location; }
        set { _location = value; }
    }

    public string VersionsName
    {
        get { return _versionsname; }
        set { _versionsname = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            Error = string.Empty;
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "Name":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
                    {
                        Error = "Error";
                    }

                    break;

                case "SelectetProgrammCategorieId":
                    if (DataStoreSingelton.Instance.AlleCategories.FirstOrDefault(S => ((List<int>)SelectetProgrammCategorieIds).FirstOrDefault(s => s == S.ID) == S.ID) != null)
                    {
                        Error = "Please enter a vaild programm categorie";
                    }

                    break;
                default: break;
            }
            return Error;
        }
    }
}
    }
```

it Seems like DevExpress just accept an object in binding ... i could use an Converter but this would just an Workaround

Im using the 12.1.5 version